# Bootstrap column reordering on small screens

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I have the following layout on a page:
[image: page layout]

Code:

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel">...//Panel1..</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel">...//Panel2..</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel">...//Panel3..</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel">...//Panel4..</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine until I add collapsing to Panels..

Now after collapsing Panel1 or Panel2 i have this effect:

[image]

Is any posibility to fix this with keep panel order on small screens?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clarified -> Now I have '[1]' but I want to achieve '[2]'

Answer (score 0):

Just add a common `min-height` to the panels so they can maintain the same height whether toggle or not.